# Navigation menu, remove item from desktop

Tags: menus, navigation, mobile, responsive

Using theme (and child theme) of Sailent, I'm trying to work out a way to completely remove a menu item from my navigation bar while on desktop. See site here: http://www.boinginflatables.com/2017update/

[image: It's there, although not visible]
As you can see, the text for the menu item isn't there, yet it messes up the alignment of the menu.

At the moment, I have that menu item set to a css class of mobile-only with css settings as:

```
.mobile-only {
        visibility:hidden;
    }
@media (min-width:992px) {
    .desktop-only {
        visibility:visible !important;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
    .mobile-only {
        visibility:visible !important;
    }

    .desktop-only {
        visibility:hidden !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this is not really a WordPress question, but the `visibility` property does not actually HIDE any element. It only fades it so you can't see it, but it still reserves space for it. You need to use the `display` property:

```
.mobile-only {
        display:hidden;
    }
@media (min-width:992px) {
    .desktop-only {
        display:block !important;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
    .mobile-only {
        display:block!important;
    }

    .desktop-only {
        display:hidden !important;
    }
}
```

You might want to change the `block` to `inline-block` or `inline`, depending on the original value of your menu's item (which is usually `inline-block`).

Comment: Thanks Jack! I tried this, however it still displays on desktop

Comment: @Liam You're welcome. If `visibility:hidden` works for you, then `display:none` will work too.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet on wordpress.stackexchange.com (not enough reputation...), but I'd like to add to the answer of *Jack Johansson from Jun 1 '17* :
The syntax for "display" is not "*hidden*" but "*none*". So the corrected code would be

```
.mobile-only {
    display:none;
}
@media (min-width:992px) {
    .desktop-only {
        display:block !important;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
    .mobile-only {
        display:block!important;
    }

    .desktop-only {
        display:none !important;
    }
}
```

While "hidden" is correct for "visibility", it isn't for "display". See https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/display for all possible values.

I'd argue that moving the first rule into the media-query would be even better and might save you from using the *!important* keyword, too, but that might depend on your theme or your other CSS rules.